# Cassandra spark connector write nested optional case class

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

How to write optional case classes with cassandra spark connector ?

example :

```
case class User(name : String, address : Option[Address])
case class Address(street : String, city : String)
```

When I tried to save user to cassandra with `rdd.saveToCassandra` it's raise an error

```
Failed to get converter for field "address" of type scala.Option[Address] in User mapped to column "address" of "testspark.logs_raw"
```

I have tried to implement a `TypeConverter` but that has not worked.

However nested case classes are correctly converted to cassandra UDT and optional fields are accepted.

Any good way to deal with that without changing the data model?

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a data frame and saving afterwards?

Comment: Yes but it's imply a lot of boiler plate. I would like to have just on json serializer un unserializer to note have probleme when there is field update. Play json allow us to juste have to manage our case class fields and it's very conveignant for know

Answer (score 1):

Just for visibility.  Everything works fine in the modern versions - there were a lot of changes in UDTs around SCC 1.4.0-1.6.0, plus many performance optimizations in the SCC 2.0.8.   With SCC 2.5.1, RDD API correctly maps everything - for example, if we have following UDT & table:

```
cqlsh> create type test.address (street text, city text);
cqlsh> create table test.user(name text primary key, address test.address);
cqlsh> insert into test.user(name, address) values 
   ('with address', {street: 'street 1', city: 'city1'});
cqlsh> insert into test.user(name) values ('without address');
cqlsh> select * from test.user;

 name            | address
-----------------+-------------------------------------
    with address | {street: 'street 1', city: 'city1'}
 without address |                                null

(2 rows)
```

Then RDD API is able to correctly pull everything when reading data:

```scala
scala> import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

scala> case class Address(street : String, city : String)
defined class Address

scala> case class User(name : String, address : Option[Address])
defined class User

scala> val data = sc.cassandraTable[User]("test", "user")
data: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[User] = CassandraTableScanRDD[0] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:18

scala> data.collect
res0: Array[User] = Array(User(without address,None), 
   User(with address,Some(Address(street 1,city1))))
```